# How to take print out of the code of github repo ?

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo and I want to take printouts of its code, now i can copy/paste the code a word document and then can take the print out but I was wondering, is there any easy and better way to do this ? as I have some 40 files

Answer (score 1):

First you would have to [`git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) the repository from github to your local filesystem.

And then on a Linux (and maybe on a Mac) machine you can use [`lpr` command](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?lpr) to print out files through the terminal.

Comment: Then you can use `git checkout <commit>` to navigate through the differents versions of your code and print it easily.

Comment: @mcamier - got it, actually I already have the code on my local system, it looks there is no direct way to print github code

Comment: @iCyborg What do you mean by direct?

Comment: You want to see the distant code directly through the terminal ? according to me, it's not possible. :S You have to pull it, maybe in another branch and then you can watch it.